# Select rows of pandas dataframe based on string in nested list

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nested-lists

How can I select a subset of a pandas dataframe based on the condition if a column which is a nested list contains a given string.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [12, 34, 43], 'course': ['Mathematics', 'Sport', 'Biology'], 'students': [['John Doe', 'Peter Parker', 'Lois Lane'], ['Bruce Banner', 'Lois Lane'], ['John Doe', 'Bruce Banner']]})
```

And now I would like to select all rows in which John Doe is in the students.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df[df.students.apply(lambda row: "John Doe" in row)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized option:

```
df[(df['students'].explode() == 'John Doe').groupby(level=0).any()]
```

Comment: This is not performant compared to apply. The explode and followed by groupby consumes time.

Comment: @SomeDude Yep - you are correct.  Just timed it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str methods (first join list to ',' separated values and then look for 'John Doe'):

```
df[df['students'].str.join(',').str.match('John Doe')]
```

But actually the `apply` method can be more performant.

The `timeit` for a bigger dataframe containing 27 rows(repeated the original df):

```
%timeit df[df['students'].str.join(',').str.match('John Doe')]
382 µs ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df[df.students.apply(lambda row: "John Doe" in row)]
271 µs ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Output:

```
   id       course                             students
0  12  Mathematics  [John Doe, Peter Parker, Lois Lane]
2  43      Biology             [John Doe, Bruce Banner]
```